# How to restructure the mezzanine project_template directory

Tags: python, django, directory-structure, mezzanine, project-template

Is there a way to re-structure the mezzanine project_template directory?

When you install a django project you get a directory with wsgi.py, settings.py, urls.py, etc.py and a file called manage.py

I want this same structure when i install a mezzanine project. Put all the files into a "settings" directory except the manage.py file.

```
/project-root/
/project-root/manage.py
/project-root/settings/
/project-root/settings/__init__.py
/project-root/settings/fabfile.py
/project-root/settings/local_settings.py
/project-root/settings/requirements.txt
/project-root/settings/settings.py
/project-root/settings/urls.py
/project-root/settings/wsgi.py
```

Thanks,

Iván